# Date.Parse with a custom formatter date

Tags: javascript

How can I get only **Fri Nov 13 2015 03:00:00** from this ?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var d2 = new Date(Date.parse("2015-11-12T20:00:00-05:00"));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d2;
}
</script>
```

now i get this **Fri Nov 13 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (E. Europe Standard Time)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can use [Moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com), you can either download the library as a file or with npm or bower. Import it to your project, once you have the variable where your date is stored you can do the following

```
var theDate = moment(d2).format('ddd MMM DD YY hh:mm:ss')
```

You should see something like this:

```
Friday Nov 13 2015 03:00:00
```

I hope it helps if you have another question, let me know i'll be happy to help you. ;)